# pythonic way of changing old names by new names

Tags: python

I have to replace the oldnames as the newnames inside the program as follows:

```
oldnames = ['apple','banana','sheep']

for oldname in oldnames:
    if oldname == 'apple':
        newname = 'monkey'

    if oldname == 'banana':
        newname = 'monkey'

    if oldname == 'sheep':
        newname = 'lion'
```

My program is doing well, but wondering what is the best pythonic way of doing it?

Comment: Are there any rules for going from ```oldname``` to ```newname```?

Comment: Exactly as used in the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also using dictionaries, but I think this is simpler:

```
# Original values
oldnames = ["apple", "banana", "sheep"]

# Conversion table
translate = {
    "apple": "monkey",
    "banana": "monkey",
    "sheep": "lion",
}

# For each oldname, get the translated value
newnames = [translate.get(x) for x in oldnames]
```

Comment: Having a list of `newnames` is superfluous if you have the dictionary. To actually use the `newnames`, you'd have to look at the `oldnames` list to get the index and then look it up in the `newnames` list. The dictionary serves this purpose for any use case.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a dictionary to handle the replacements, for example

```
>>> replacements = {'apple':'monkey',
                    'banana':'monkey',
                    'sheep':'lion'}
>>> s = "The apple and the banana saw a sheep"
>>> ' '.join(replacements.get(word,word) for word in s.split())
'The monkey and the monkey saw a lion'
```

Comment: They are inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

even more pythonic

```
oldnames = ["apple", "banana", "sheep"]
translate = { "apple": "monkey", "banana": "monkey", "sheep": "lion" }

newnames = map(translate.get, oldnames)
```